Is Cassandra in Docker supported on Windows?
We use Cassandra with Teamwork Cloud and was wondering if Apache supports the implementation of Cassandra using Docker for Windows?  I see it is mentioned in the "Quick Start" instructions but want to verify Apache supports Cassandra implemented on Docker of Windows.

Deploying Cassandra on Windows is supported either as (a) Docker container, or (b) with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) but (c) only for development environments.
I acknowledge that the word "support" is ambiguous so I will say that we do not recommend deploying Cassandra on Windows for production environments.
Deployments on Windows have been problematic for a very long time and we gave up testing on Windows due to issues with Java file I/O on NTFS. It was a constant source of problems for the project so Windows support was dropped in 2020 (see the discussion thread and CASSANDRA-16171). Cheers!
